Query to search from the first Monday of every month through the last week period of every month
How would I create an SQL Oracle query that searches full 7 day periods starting on Monday and ending on Sundays. It would need to start on the first Monday of each month and, to include the full 7 day period, would need to end on the next Sunday the last day of the month would fall on.
For example:
An August 2024 report would need to be the date range of 08/05/2024 - 09/01/2024.
A September 2024 report would need to be the date range of 09/02/2024 - 10/06/2024
I have this to start with, but it pulls the first and last day of the month. I want to extend it to start on the first Monday and end through to Sunday of the last day.
with
date_range as (
select start_date, end_date, 4 num_weeks_queried
from (
  select add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1) start_date,
  last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1)) end_date from dual
)


You can use:
SELECT CASE
       WHEN week_start < month_start
       THEN week_start + INTERVAL '7' DAY
       ELSE week_start
       END AS start_date,
       CASE
       WHEN week_end < month_end
       THEN week_end + INTERVAL '7' DAY
       ELSE week_end
       END - INTERVAL '1' SECOND AS end_date
FROM   (
  SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM') AS month_start,
         TRUNC(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 'IW') AS week_start,
         ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 1) AS month_end,
         TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 1), 'IW') AS week_end
  FROM   DUAL
)

Which outputs:



START_DATE
END_DATE




2024-08-05 00:00:00
2024-09-01 23:59:59



fiddle
